# Delegating Listeners to an ID in XTemplate (ExtJS)

Tags: delegates, extjs, listener

I am working with Listeners + XTemplate.

Our goal is to delegate an 'itemtap' listener to an ID in XTemplate (i.e. div id="xplay").

Error received:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 undefined event_bindings:207
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:207
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage miscellaneous_bindings:250
```

Here's our XTemplate:

```
var itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<img src="http://www.myShortenedUrl.com/{taskImgPath}" />',
        '<img src="http://www.myShortenedUrl.com/{timeImgPath}" />',
        '<div id="xplay">',
            '<img src="http://www.starrbc.org/play_button.jpg" />',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

Here's our xtype: list with the XTemplate (*itemTpl*) binded to it, and an itemtap listener that is delegated to "xplay":

```
xtype: 'panel',
items: [{
    xtype: 'list',
    id: 'bookmarkView',
    store: bookmarkStore,
    itemTpl: itemTpl, // setting the XTemplate here
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(bookmarkView, index, item, e){
            console.log("Hello I am Here!");
        },
        element: 'innerElement',
        delegate: 'xplay'
    }
```

We removed `element: 'innerElement'` and `delegate: 'xplay'` and it will trigger the `itemtap` function when we click on ANY part of the XTemplate, but that isn't our goal. We would like only our PLAY button to trigger this listener.

### Update

Thanks Evan for the quick response.

Here's what I tried with your inputs - let me know if I'm doing it wrongly.

Changed div id to div class.

```
var itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<img src="http://www.myShortenedUrl.com/{taskImgPath}" />',
        '<div class="xplay">',
            '<img src="http://src.sencha.io/200/http://www.starrbc.org/play_button.jpg" />',
        '</div><br/>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

I added the check for the event object, commented the codes away for element and delegate (leaving these there won't work).

```
listeners: {
    itemtap: function(bookmarkView, index, item, e) {
                console.log("Hello I am Here!");

                if (e.getTarget().hasCls('xplay')) {
                    console.log('hasCls: xplay');
                }
            } //,
    // element: 'innerElement',
    // delegate: 'xplay'
}
```

However, we encountered this problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTarget'
>   Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception
>   1 undefined

We're confused, does that mean we're not getting an Event object? Or have we interpreted your explanation wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way.

1) ID's should be unique, you can't repeat the id over and over, there has to be one per element. Instead, give the element a class name.

2) Listen to the itemtap event as you have been doing, then check the event object to see if it matches your delegate:

```
if (e.getTarget().hasCls('myCustomCls')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listeners: {
    element: 'element',//i hope element works.
    delegate: 'div.xplay',
    event:'tap',
    fn: 'Your function here',
}
```

This is how the listener should be for your requirement.